# sed for dictionary keyword

Tags: json, regex, sed, jq

My json looks as below

> {"servers": 
>    [{"server_type":"application_server","server_url":"application_server.com"},{"server_type":"relay_server","server_url":"application_server.com"}] }

I need to replace server_url ( **application_server.com** ) to a different value say (**application2_server.com**) using sed or any  regex .

Comment: Why not using a json parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jq` json parser!

```
jq '.servers[].server_url="application2_server.com"' file
```

Comment: or the built-in `json` library!

Comment: @Nordle Built-in where?

Comment: @BenjaminW. it's a built-in in Python - [json](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#module-json)

Comment: @Nordle Ah, okay. Just didn't see Python mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ah! Completely correct, I'm so used to looking only at Python questions that I assumed before writing, oops!